# Vertical ScrollView with nested horizontal ScrollView not positioned correctly after each data population

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, maui

On iPad (but not iPhone or Android tablet), ScrollView after each population of elements with data and regeneration of the layout accordingly is initially appearing in the wrong place on the screen. After rotation from landscape to portrait, or vice versa, however, positioning of ScrollView is correct, and after rotation back to the original orientation, positioning is correct.

[Incorrect positioning (before rotation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ouK.png)

[Correct positioning (after rotation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsEYX.png)

Nesting hierarchy of elements is as follows:

grid
gridFixed
webView
gridPart
scrollView
scrollStackLayout
gridWorkSteps
Label
stackSegs
Label, Label, Label...
scrollHView
stackParams
StackLayout
Label, Label, Label...
StackLayout
Entry, Entry, Entry...
StackLayout
Entry, Entry, Entry...
StackLayout
Picker, Picker, Picker...
.
.
.
.

Each StackLayout under stackParams is populated with data for the parameter that corresponds to it for each work step of the current part, initially and each time a different part is loaded.

Putting stackParams directly under gridWorkSteps (removing the horizontal ScrollView, scrollHView, from the hierarchy) avoids the problem, but there are too many parameters (columns) to fit in a fixed view. Also, there are indefinitely many work steps, so a vertical ScrollView is also necessary.

By trial and error, I found I could mitigate the problem by regenerating the layout a second time 100 milliseconds after the data population completes. With this kludge, the mispositioning still occurs, but only briefly before correcting. (I would consider the kludge acceptable if the mispositioning did not appear at all.)

This problem does not occur either on iPhone or Android tablet.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting

Comment: Thank you, Jason, for this response. Can you be specific about how I could improve my question?

Comment: post the relevant code.  You posted several paragraphs of text *describing* a complex UI when it would be much more efficient to post the actual code (or a representative subset).  See [mcve]

Comment: It likely will turn out to be a subtle bug in Maui's attempt to measure/position this complex layout. Start a new Maui project. Put in just enough code to cause the bug. Simplify as much as possible. Add the most relevant code (as copyable text) to the question. Also make a public github repo that can be run. If no one spots a fix that can be made, then make a new `github maui issue` with a link to that repo.

Comment: Very interesting case you got. I really want to see your page xaml file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could try to handle the position when the screen is rotated. [Reacting to Changes in Orientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows#reacting-to-changes-in-orientation)